# Read textfile with delimiters at all lines

Tags: php

I have a textfile that looks like this:

```
NAME=ARTHUR
LASTNAME=McConnell
AGE=43
```

What I would like to do with it is get an array like this:

```
Array (
 [NAME] => ARTHUR
 [LASTNAME] => McConnell
 [AGE] => 43
)
```

All help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried to do to get this accomplished so far? What code have you written? Where are you getting stuck in this code?

Comment: You could try using `explode` in combination with a loop www.php.net/explode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$filename = 'info.txt';

//Read the file into a line-by-line array
$contents = file($filename);

//Loop through each line
foreach($contents as $line) {
    //Split by the = sign
    $temp_array = explode('=', $line);
    //Rebuild new array
    $new_array[$temp_array[0]] = $temp_array[1];
}

//Print out the array at the end for testing
var_dump($new_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the exact same syntax for your file format you can use `parse_ini_file()`. It don't cares about the file extension, so you can apply it on `.txt` files too, as long as the format is correct.

**test.txt**

```
NAME=ARTHUR
LASTNAME=McConnell
AGE=43
```

**parser.php**

```
<?php

$data = parse_ini_file('test.txt');

var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `parse_ini_file`

```
$data = parse_ini_file('myFile.txt');
```

or use `explode` two times

```
// first in end of lines
$data = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('myFile.txt'));

// and after, make a loop on the resulting array and creating a new array
$arr = array();

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $line = explode("=", $row);

    $arr[$line[0]] = $line[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think that I have given it in a variable

```
$variable = "NAME=ARTHUR
LASTNAME=McConnell
AGE=43"
//instead of this you can read the whole file
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $variable);
```